# Methode Call twice inside LINQ Query

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

In our application we have a little query that looks like this:

```
var selectedAgents = from agent in listAgents
    where (this.collectionVehicles.GetVehicleByAgent(agent)).IsActive || 
          (this.collectionVehicles.GetVehicleByAgent(agent)).IsSoldSinceCurrentSession 
           select agent;
```

This works fine but the method GetVehicleByAgent is called two times and this is maybe not necessary.

Before LINQ we had a foreach-loop and did like this:

```
Vehicle parentVehicle = collectionVehicles.GetVehicleByAgent(agent);

if (parentVehicle.IsActive || parentVehicle.IsSoldSinceCurrentSession)
{
    selectedAgents.Add(agent);
}
```

As you can see GetVehicleByAgent returns a Vehicle object and that can easiely compared more than once. So I am looking for a way the retieve the Vehicle inside the LINQ query and keep it. I don't want to call GetVehicleByAgent twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [`let` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx), like this:

```
var selectedAgents =
    from agent in listAgents
    let parentVehicle = collectionVehicles.GetVehicleByAgent(agent)
    where parentVehicle.IsActive || parentVehicle.IsSoldSinceCurrentSession 
    select agent;
```